# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I'm trying to delete a UITableView sections

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have this code:

```
    // - Update the data source
    self.order.persons.removeAtIndex(index)

    // - Disable the user interaction
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false

    // - Delete the needed section from the table view
    let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: self.order.persons.count - 1)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.deleteSections(sectionIndexSet, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()

    // - Update the table view with a delay to update all the indexes 
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, handler: {
            self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

So the problem:

- CASE 1: When on the visible zone of table view are another sections, not only the one that I want to delete, all works great.
- CASE 2: When on the visible zone of table view is ONLY the section that I want to delete, the debugger stop at the line:

  `self.tableView.endUpdates()`

and gives the errors :

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).`

I don't understand why case 1 is working great, but case 2 not. For information, I use reusable cells.

Comment: please, share the whole stacktrace

Comment: First of all, you must use the `NSIndexSet` initializer with `row` and `section` parameters. Second of all delete the `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates` and `reloadData` lines, `deleteSections` rearranges the table view automatically and `begin/endUpdates` is not needed for a single delete operation. And last but not least you have to delete all appropriate items also in the data source array **before** calling  `deleteSections`.

Comment: @vadian I've tried without `begin/endUpdates` or `reloadData` and the same result. `NSIndexSet` has not an initializer with row and section, `NSIndexPath` has one, but in my case I need to delete a section, so I can't use `NSIndexPath`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Of course `NSIndexSet` is correct. But do you delete also the whole section in the data source array?

Comment: @vadian yes, `self.order.persons.removeAtIndex(index)` are doing this, each section has only one row, so it's enough. The problem is that the crash occurs only when the section that I want to delete takes the entire visible rect of the `tableView` , when on the screen is visible another section, let say 1px of another cell from the second section, the deletion is working as expected.

Comment: I'd try to delete the row explicitly and then the section.

Comment: @vadian I've tried this, in that case I will receive inconsistence between `dataSource` and the `tableView` update generating the error : `Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).` 
The only solution that worked for me, was to have all the cells in an array, preinitialized and for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` return the needed cell.

Comment: Manipulating the view that way is very bad programming habit. The MVC pattern suggests to manipulate the model and call the respective  insert/delete/move/reload method of the table view. Maybe there is another issue how the reusable cells are handled.

Comment: @vadian yes, I understand, I've done this to analyse the problem. Finally only the `reloadData` doesn't crash even using reusable cells, but there are no animations :(.

Comment: In your code
// - Delete the needed section from the table view
    let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: self.order.persons.count - 1)
===============================
shouldn't it use index, instead you are using self.order.persons.count - 1

Answer (score 0):

You are removing different data from source and in tableView

**ISSUE**

```
 // - Delete the needed section from the table view
    let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: self.order.persons.count - 1)
```

**FIX**
It should be

```
// - Delete the needed section from the table view
    let sectionIndexSet = NSIndexSet(index: index)
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's a logic problem, thanks. But the problem with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` remains.

Comment: What triggers the deletion of a section in your table view?

Comment: One of the reason behind EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) is  when there is a difference in Data source and the sections being visible in UITableView. I would suggest you to recheck your code for any of such logical issue!